# Active Passive mode supported for GCP external Load Balancer towards VM instance NIC0?

Tags: google-cloud-network-load-balancer

Failover for GCP internal load balancer has recently been introduced in Google Cloud PLatform

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal/failover-overview

Now I would like to know if we can also use this on the External GCP Load Balancer. Does someone know if this feature is available?

Best regards,

Marvin

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently not supported for L7 Load Balancers (both external and internal). These setting appears to be supported for only L4 ILB as you already mentioned it was described in the public docs [Failover for Internal TCP/UDP Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal/failover-overview).

You could also file a [Feature Request](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/create-issue-ui) for this implementation and get the Google team aware of the benefits in your scenario.